# Get data from 3 tables using sql join query based on a id (cdid)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm tried to get results from Mysql 3 tables using sql join query. It's showing me error message when I'm running it. Like :

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 
D:\software installed\xampp\htdocs\contact-management\getContactDetails.php on line 15
```

Well, I've 3 table. 1) company 2) contact_details 3) users.

**Column on company Table (3):**

```
cid, company_name, created_date
```

**Column on contact_details Table (10):**

```
cdid, family_name, given_name, work_phone, mobile_phone, email, email_private, 
user_id, cid, created_date.
```

**Column on users Table ():**

```
user_id, username, nickname
```

**So what Im trying to do is**.....I want to get all `contact_details` table info with `company name`, `username` and `nickname` from `company` and `users` table. So It's  should only show one set of result.

So that My sql join query is look like this :

```
$id  = (int) $_POST['id']; // this is based id which coming from contact_details (cdid)

$innerjoing =  mysql_query("SELECT contact_details.*, company.company_name,   
users.nickname
FROM users
INNER JOIN (contact_details INNER JOIN company ON contact_details.cid =   
company.$id)
ON users.user_id = contact_details.user_id");
```

But bad luck I'm not getting what i want.

Comment: will you share your php code where you wrote mysql_fetch_array($innerjoing);? There may be an issue with variable name that you have passed to the function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is an error with your code at `contact_details INNER JOIN company ON contact_details.cid = company.$id` **company.$id** is wrong syntax for query.

[Rajavel D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24486612/2679536) 's query is correct as per your requirement.

You can also try :

```
$innerjoing =  mysql_query("SELECT contact_details . * , company.company_name, users.nickname
    FROM contact_details
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = contact_details.user_id
    LEFT JOIN company ON company.cid = contact_details.cid
    WHERE contact_details.cdid = ".$id)
```

If still you're not getting, Please check your variable what you've passed to the function.
It should be `mysql_fetch_array($innerjoing);`

[Refer this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: Most welcome, I have given too many options.. which one is perfect for you??

Comment: Your sql query is just perfect for me now.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have give the $id is wrong and query as well :

Try This :

```
("SELECT cd.*, c.company_name, u.nickname, u.username  
  FROM contact_details cd INNER JOIN user u 
       ON cd.user_id = u.user_id
          INNER JOIN company c on cd.cid=c.cid 
              where cd.cdid = " . $id )
```

Comment: I'm trying with this.

Comment: tell me after trying, whether its working or any issue

Comment: may be your query is wrong. Because this `$id` (cdid) is come from contact_details table. So how do you compare it with `cd.user_id = $id` ?

Comment: now you check i have changes cdid instead of user_id

Comment: No, Not based on user id. I've to show details based on `cdid` which is come from `contact_details` table. This `cdid` is a primary key of this table. In `contact_details` table I've `cid`, `user_id` when I'm inserting data into this table.

Comment: now you check i have changes cdid instead of user_id

Comment: Still showing same error message.

Comment: now you check i put the condition check in where

Comment: You are trying hard. But unfortunately it's not working now. Getting same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $innerjoing =  mysql_query("
 SELECT cd.*, c.company_name, u.nickname
 FROM contact_details cd
 INNER JOIN user u on cd.user_id = u.user_id
 INNER JOIN company c on cd.cid = c.cid
 where c.cid = " + $id);
```

Comment: in where it should cd.ccid instead of c.cid as per the Shibbir requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
select cd.*,company_name,username,nickname 
from 
    contact_details as cd 
left join 
    company as c
on 
    cd.cid = c.cid
left join 
    users as u
on 
    cd.user_id = u.user_id `
```